# Full rigor in defining a map of groups or metric spaces

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces

I apologize if this is obvious. Typically, when we talk about groups or metric spaces, we don't write $(G, \star)$ or $(X,d)$, but rather refer to the "group" or the "metric space" as the underlying sets, $G$ and $X$, respectively, with the group law and metric understood. This is surely an abuse of notation, but a somewhat harmless one.

Suppose I have two groups: $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_{+}, \times)$, i.e., the reals under addition and the positive reals under multiplication. These are isomorphic as groups via the exponential map. But would I define the group homomorphism as a *map of sets* or as a map of *groups*? For example, would I wrote $f: (\mathbb{R}, +) \to (\mathbb{R}_{+}, \times)$ or $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$, i.e., is this a map of *groups* or a map of *sets*? Even if it's a map of sets, I can still "talk" about the underlying operation.

Similarly, if I have metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, I have seen, in the context of proving statements about, say, continuity, people refer to maps $f: (X,d_X) \to (Y,d_Y)$, and refer to them as maps of metric spaces, and to maps $f: X \to Y$ and refer to them as maps of sets. Which is correct?

My view, from what I understand, is that the operation/metric are somewhat immaterial to the map, but rather understood from the groups/metric spaces themselves, so these are, truly, maps of *sets*, but we still think about what happens with the operation/metric. Is this on-track?

Comment: Both notation are correct. It is just the question of how much detail you want to give.

Comment: Technically, a group is a set together with **three** operations: a binary operation $\cdot$, a unary operation ${}^{-1}$, and a nullary operation $e$. So groups should be $4$-tuples, $(G,\cdot,{}^{-1},e)$, where $G$ is a set, $\cdot$ is a binary operation, etc. Morphisms are maps $(G,\cdot,{}^{-1},e)\to (H,\odot,{}^{-1},\mathbf{e})$, which are functions $f\colon G\to H$, and satisfy `blah`. Etc. You can see the treatment with full care and formalism in, for example, George Bergman’s [Invitation to General Algebra](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $G$ should be a non-empty set

Comment: @CSquared: Having a nullary operation on a set implies the set is nonempty. There is no need to specify it explicitly in that setting.